# Not able to upload file using Windows file upload popup, tried using Java Robot class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I'm writing Automation test case to upload file using Java Selemium. My problem is when I click on upload button, Windows file upload popup appears.
I tried using Robot class to send file path in popup window it does not type anything, i guess it is not able to set focus on popup window. Tried using `driver.switchTo().alert()` as well.

My code is as follows:

```java
List<WebElement> elecount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/img[@title='Insert pictures inline']"));
        elecount.get(1).click(); //opens the Windows popup


        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("File path");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
        try{
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        }
```

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a bit, found the solution, there is an absolute Xpath that can be used to directly send a file path to upload. Here  is the code:

File a = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"your absolute path"); //In my case, file exist in project directory.

String absolute = a.getCanonicalPath();

WebElement addfile = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='file']")); //This absolute Xpath is used to directly upload a file without need to to open Windows file upload popup.

addfile.sendKeys(absolute);